# How to use both C# code and javascript functions in an asp.net website

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website where the user opens up a picture in an ImageButton web control. They can then click around and retrieve the distance between pairs of clicks. As the user keeps clicking the distance is added to an int variable total. This total can then be set as the value of an active cell in an Excel spreadsheet with the push of an asp.net Button.

The OnClientClick events of the ImageButton are handled by the functions in a JavaScript file, along with the variables correspond to distance and total. I chose to do this in javascript because it is easy to avoid a postback. The Button OnClick events which set the ImageButton URL and pass the total to Excel are handled in a C# code file. Since OnClick in C# only work with a postback, the total is passed to an asp: HiddenField everytime it is updated through the javascript functions

The javascript functions work well on their own (without doing a postback) when the ImageButton URL is preset, and without any hidden fields. However, once I add in the C# code and pass the javascript variables to their corresponding hidden fields, a postback occurs and the data is still lost.

How do I make sure the javascript functions execute without a postback even when separate OnClick events execute?

Here is the javascript:

```
var pos1x = 0, pos1y = 0;
var pos2x = 0, pos2y = 0;
var distx = 0, disty = 0;
var redistx = 0, redisty = 0, newdist = 0;
var runtotal = 0;
var numClick = 0;

function Pic_Click() {
    numClick++;
    document.getElementById("labelcount").innerText = "Count: " + numClick;
    var rem = numClick % 2;
    if (rem == 1) {
        pos1x = event.pageX;
        pos1y = event.pageY;
    }
    else {
        pos2x = event.pageX;
        pos2y = event.pageY;
        distx = Math.abs(pos2x - pos1x);
        disty = Math.abs(pos2y - pos1y);
        redistx = Math.ceil(distx / 50);
        redisty = Math.ceil(disty / 50);
        newdist = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(redistx * redistx + redisty * redisty));
        document.getElementById("labelrun").innerText = "Distance: " + newdist;
        total += newdist;
        document.getElementById("labeltotal").innerText = "Total: " + total;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Every time the total gets updated, I pass its value to the HiddenField by adding in  **document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value = total;** after **total += newdist;**.

The picture is opened with the C# method:

```
protected void UploadIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
    filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    fullpath = Path.Combine("~/Files/" + filename);

    ext = Path.GetExtension(fullpath);
    imgholder.ImageUrl = fullpath;      
}
```

The Web Controls are created in the .aspx file:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgholder" runat="server" OnClientClick="Pic_Click(); return false;" />
<asp:Button ID="Up" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadIt"/>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You might want to look at an `UpdatePanel`, or do a full Ajax solution that will call generic handler file.

Comment: The UpdatePanel does help with uploading files via C#, but how do I use it help me with the javascript?

Comment: An update panel will take the current state of the site dump it into memory, then update via a postback keeping a large portion of the page state.  Allowing the use of a full server side control usage and the execution of JavaScript for specific functions on reload.  If you are controlling page state with JavaScript, you should use all ajax and generic handler files.